# How Do I Display Data From Two Different Collection's Documents in Spacebars #each Tag?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-collections

I have 2 Collections (one of which is a standard Collection and the other is a CFS Collection to store my uploaded images):

```
Products = new Mongo.Collection('products');
```

and

```
Uploads = new FS.Collection('uploads', {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem('uploads', {path: '~/projectUploads'})]

});
```

Some documents inside the Products collection has a field or key/value pair of 'product_main_image' which stores the filename of the uploaded file that is stored in the Uploads CFS collection.

On my page I set a helper:

```
Template.admin_products.helpers({

  products: function(){
    console.log('inside helperproduct');

    return Products.find();
  }

});
```

and in the html I have:

```
{{#each products}}
    {{product_name}}
    {{product_main_image}}
  {{/each}}
```

But instead of the actual filename as displayed by `{{product_main_image}}` I would like to display the uploaded file as if I accessed it using this code:

```
Uploads.findOne({"original.name":product_main_image});
```

This page is where I display all of the products using `{{#each products}}` and I would also like to display the image for each product that is stored in the Uploads CFS Collection.

Is this possible?
and how may I achieve this?
Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this possible? **Yes**

how may I achieve this?

You can use the context of `this`. on the `Uploads.findOne()`

This is how the **HTML** should look.

```
{{#each products}}
   {{product_name}}
   {{product_main_image}}
    {{#with image}}
      <img src="{{this.url}}" />
    {{/with}}
 {{/each}}
```

And the image helper.

```
Template.example.helpers({
  image:function(){
    Uploads.findOne({"original.name":this.product_main_image});
   }
})
```

Here is a quick [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/BqeGGvf5p7cWpHrSe/Leaderboard) showing how can you achieve this (im using 2 dummy collection but the idea is the same)

Comment: Thank you...that did work... I knew how to use helpers...but I did not know how to apply it in that way...Thanks a lot :)